# Piping input into Plink in Windows batch file adds extra line feeds

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, putty, plink

I'm trying to write a batch file to run in Windows 10 Pro that will use Plink to establish an SSH session to a remote server and execute some commands.  Everything works well, except for whatever reason I end up with extra line feeds with each `ECHO` command I pipe in.  Normally, this isn't an issue, until the command I'm running requires some specific user feedback, namely, pressing `Y` to confirm an action.  Since it receives the extra line feed after testing `STSTest` command and before receiving the `Y` character, it throws an error.

Here's my batch script:

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY;%PATH%
set TestNum=%1

(
    TIMEOUT /t 1 > nul
    ECHO cd /usr/bin/core/test
    ECHO rm STS_*.txt
    ECHO rm STS_T1_Test%TestNum%.txt
    ECHO ./STSTest --T 2 --i %TestNum%
    TIMEOUT /t 1 > nul
    ECHO Y
    TIMEOUT /t 1 > nul
    ECHO exit
) | plink -ssh 192.168.1.20 -l root -pw ***
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to eliminate that extra line feed so that `Y` is entered in the correct order after the `STSTest` command is entered?

---

Here's a simpler example demonstrating what I'm fighting.  If I define this simple batch file:

```
(
    TIMEOUT /t 1 > nul
    ECHO cd /
    ECHO cd usr
    ECHO cd bin
    ECHO cd core
    ECHO cd test
    TIMEOUT /t 1 > nul
    ECHO exit
) | plink -ssh 192.168.1.20 -l root -pw ***
```

The results from the command window look like:

```
Last login: Wed Jul 29 23:53:30 2020 from 192.168.1.7
root@core-A:~# cd /
root@core-A:/#
root@core-A:/# cd usr
root@core-A:/usr#
root@core-A:/usr# cd bin
root@core-A:/usr/bin#
root@core-A:/usr/bin# cd core
root@core-A:/usr/bin/core#
root@core-A:/usr/bin/core# cd test
root@core-A:/usr/bin/core/test#
root@core-A:/usr/bin/core/test# exit
```

I get an extra line feed after every `ECHO` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are executing `plink` without any command on its command-line, `plink` starts an *interactive* terminal session. That has lot of unwanted side effects. Including those that you face.

Add [`-T` switch to `plink` command line](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty) to avoid that:

```
(
...
) | plink -T -ssh 192.168.1.20 -l root -pw ***
```

---

Another option is doing everything on the server-side and specifying full command on the `plink` commandline (in this case, you will also [need to add the `-batch` switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57735695/850848)):

```
plink -ssh 192.168.1.20 -l root -pw *** -batch "cd /usr/bin/core/test && rm STS_*.txt && rm STS_T1_Test%TestNum%.txt && (echo Y | ./STSTest --T 2 --i %TestNum%)"
```

Or some combination of both these methods.

---

Similar questions:

- [Windows batch scripting: SSH with Plink showing strange sequences in output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33904171/850848)
- [Executing command using Plink does not work, but does in PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46591648/850848)
- [Script via Plink in .bat behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38313389/850848)

Comment: With the first option I get errors from the device I'm connecting to "-sh: line 1: cd: too many arguments".  With the second option, the batch file runs smoothly, but I did have to add the -batch option to the plink call "plink -ssh -batch 192.168.1.20 -l root -pw"

Answer (score 0):

A batch file `echo` uses the Windows line ending (carriage return+line feed).

Combine the [newline hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/269819/3501) with the no line ending hack:

```
@echo off
REM don't remove blank lines below
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%

(
    <nul set /P=foo%NL%
    <nul set /P=foo%NL%bar%NL%
) > test.txt
```

and test.txt becomes (hex output)

```
66 6F 6F 0A 66 6F 6F 0A 62 61 72 0A     foo.foo.bar.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried that, and unfortunately it seems like it is removing all new line characters.  The session enters the "./STSTest --T 2 --i %TestNum%" line, and sits there until the 3 seconds times out and the "ECHO Y" line executes, which then adds "Y" and a new line to the end of the first line, and I miss the response window.

Comment: Then you should try to explain better what you need. Each ECHO ends with a newline unless you use a hack...

Comment: I updated my original post with the issue I am encountering.  It's like the ECHO command is sending two different line feeds every time it's invoked.

Comment: I tried an example I found like this earlier and it didn't work.  I figured I would try again by copy/pasting your example, and I get the same results.  The command session hangs when I try to use the %NL% variable.  However, I think I have figured out a way past it with Martin's help.  Thank you for your replies.